# cloudwatch to opensearch lambda filter subscription error

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

So i want to send cloudwatch data to opensearch, testing from the built in cloudwatch log group filter `cloudwatch to opensearch` this creates a lambda using nodejs.16, hardcodes the index to `cwl` and all works lovely.

I want to be able to specify the index name and not always have it go to cwl.

I toke the working node function copied and altered it from:

```
        // index name format: cwl-YYYY.MM.DD
        var indexName = [
            'cwl-' + timestamp.getUTCFullYear(),              // year
            ('0' + (timestamp.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),  // month
            ('0' + timestamp.getUTCDate()).slice(-2)          // day
        ].join('.');
```

to

```
        // index name format: INDEX_NAME-YYYY.MM.DD
        var indexName = [
            process.env.INDEX_NAME,
            '-' + timestamp.getUTCFullYear(),              // year
            ('0' + (timestamp.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),  // month
            ('0' + timestamp.getUTCDate()).slice(-2)          // day
        ].join('.');
```

which now gives me the error:

```
2023-10-20T16:09:29.279Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'snapshot'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'snapshot'",
        "Require stack:",
        "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
        "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1087:17)",
        "    at async Object.UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)",
        "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)",
        "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"
    ]
}
```

- If i do a diff. that is the only change to the code
- They both use the same iam role sp cant see that being the problem?

Any ideas what ive done wrong?

Comment: The error is not with the new `indexName`, you're missing a module: `Error: Cannot find module 'snapshot'"` Did make the change on the same Lambda function or did you copy it to a new one?

Comment: I made a new one, but the aws made function has no layers or extra files with it,.